# Is Postgres using memory context because of the limitation of C?

Tags: c++, c, postgresql, memory

[Postgres uses memory context to manage its memory.](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/tree/master/src/backend/utils/mmgr)

One advantage of doing so that I can think of is to divide all memory allocations into different contexts so that allocations in a context can be freed in bulk. However, I never met a similar concept in C++. Is it because in C++ there are smart pointers thus don't need such context? If Postgres was developed in C++, would it use smart pointers instead of memory context?

Comment: Doesn't the postgres readme already explain why they have added a mmgr layer: "The main advantage of memory contexts over plain use of malloc/free is
that the entire contents of a memory context can be freed easily, without
having to request freeing of each individual chunk within it.  This is
both faster and more reliable than per-chunk bookkeeping."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

C++ smart pointers provide no such benefit, since they still fundamentally perform individual deallocations (allocate n items, perform n deallocations), while the memory contexts here allow for bulk deallocation (allocate n items, perform 1 deallocation).

This reduced cost of deallocation (often combined with reduced overhead for performing the allocations) is the whole point of [region based memory management](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Region-based_memory_management) (the general term for this strategy).

C++ code could use this strategy, e.g. with a custom allocator that is reference counted and contains the bulk allocation, with each suballocation's deleter decrementing the reference count, with the bulk allocation being released in bulk when the count drops to zero, but it's tricky to do safely, especially if pointers might reference the data inadvertently; C has it easier since all such pointers are explicit, there's no issue with determining when constructors/destructors should occur (they don't exist), etc.

Essentially, this is a trick used in *very* specific contexts where all pointers involved are either internal to the region in which they were allocated, or not involved in region-based management. And trying to extend it to modern C++-style smart pointers and allocators introduces the same complexity those smart pointers are trying to avoid, so it's not usually worth bothering.

Point is, nothing *prevents* C++ from doing this, but it's so rarely needed (usually only in ultra-high performance low level code), that most C++ code doesn't bother. If you were writing C++ code that really needed this feature, there's a decent chance that it would benefit from hand-tuning with more direct control, causing you to write that particular component in C anyway.

C++ does reduce the need for this strategy *a little*, since smart pointers (largely) remove the risk of failing to deallocate (as the Postgres docs note, one of the advantages is that it is "more reliable" than per chunk bookkeeping, indicating it reduces the risk of a leak), so C benefits a little more, but both C and C++ benefit from reduced overhead (no per-allocation allocator memory overhead, no paying a deallocation cost for every allocation), so C++ *could* reap benefits from region based management.

Comment: I sometimes see it in C programs where people didn't want to deal with calling `free(p)` all the time, so they used some kind of "pool" for an operation then discard the entire thing, I even saw some that can take a "destructor" function pointer at "alloc" time to close files, sockets, etc. C++ calling destructors for stack variables automatically takes care of most of that though.

Comment: @FireLancer: Yeah, C's memory management is annoying, so from a convenience perspective, region based management gets you more in C than in C++. But it would still offer performance benefits to C++ if you really *needed* that benefit, it's just that very little C++ code is *that* performance-sensitive.

Comment: I think the killer feature of memory contexts is that they reduce the danger of memory leaks.